# Increase the dimensions of a Numpy array to exactly match the size of another array

Tags: numpy

I have a multidimensional array. It can have 3 or more dimensions. I also have a 2-dimensional mask array (it will always be two dimensional). I want to expand the dimensions of the mask array by copying so that it would exactly match the multidimensional array. For example:

```
data.shape = (11, 1, 1, 224, 464, 1, 224)

mask.shape = (224, 464)
```

desired output shape of mask:

```
mask.shape = (11, 1, 1, 224, 464, 1, 224)
```

One way to do it is to use numpy.repeat but the problem is that we don't know how many dimensions could data have and the function must be general in the way that it could expand the mask array to any possible dimensions. I also tried np.resize but it will ruin the spatial orientation of the mask.

Comment: You probably need some 'if' tests on the number of dimensions.  `repeat` is powerful, and can work with specific axes, but you still need to specify them.  `tile` is a further genrralization of `repeat`.  I don't what `resize` would do for you.  I think you just have to work out the details youself.  Your goal is too vague and/or general.

Comment: @hpaulj The thing is data can be any shape, such as (10, 224, 464) or (224, 464, 10 , 10). 224 and 464 are y (lat) and x(lon) of the image and mask is a bool array that I want to use to clip data array. So I thought the best way to do it is to match the size of mask and data.

Comment: `broadcast_to` is another tool